# flutter crash, clang, new build system, targets in parallel, analyzing workspace

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator, flutter-test, runner

I am trying to run a flutter app on an iOS simulator. Latest version of flutter. I tried the following commands all of which resulted in this crash.

flutter build

flutter run --no-sound-null-safety

flutter clear and then flutter build

```
ld: 35 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace     
note: Constructing build description     
note: Build preparation complete
```